# How to enable second level cache in Hibernate 5.2.2?

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

This post tries to explain how to enable caching in Hibernate 5.2.2 as it requires additional configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For enabling second level cache in Hibernate 5.2.2, along with setting use_second_level_cache to true, and providing provider class using provider_class. We also need to set the cache.region.factory class.

hibernate.cfg.xml changes below :

```
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>

    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

Comment: "hibernate.cache.provider_class" is no longer a configuration property, see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations

Answer (score 0):

For properties file

```
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```